# "На предмет"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Попалось в тексте предложение (привожу фрагмент): "...подвергаются тестированию на предмет, способны ли они..."
Грамотно ли построено предложение и не нужно ли тут добавить "на предмет *того*..."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А не лучше ли " Подвергаются тестированию на способность...  " . Дальше, наверное, инфинитив (например, способность что делать? находить... ). Но для грамотной правки контекст должен быть шире!